# How to host a good number of images for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, database, xcode, image, hosting

we want to create an iOS game in which users guess different pictures. For that, the game will have plenty of randomized images.

So here's the thing, we're looking to create a database of images.

What do you guys recommend to create such a database and host all of these images?

I've heard about **SQLite**, but we're pretty lost on how to move forward.

Thanks!

Comment: if one of these was the correct solution for you could you please mark it as such? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in SQLite you can store an image as a BLOB  or you can save in a folder and save the URL in the DB as a TEXT.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any recommendations on databases?

Comment: SQLite works good and I think that if you want to download the images from the server is better with storing the URL in data base and then you can use threads to download the images one by one, else you will download all the database doing a hard work.

Answer (score 0):

If your images aren't super high-quality/not huge in size, I'd suggest trying a image map.

Keep a table of starting coordinates + image size to dereference each image.

*Note:* This works best when images are all the same size.

Comment: Image map? Like placing the images in a plist?

Comment: Nuh-uh...like this: http://spritedatabase.net/files/nes/228/Sprite/MapSprites.gif  <-- although these are sprites. :D So you have just one image file for a bunch of separate images.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! What program do you recommend for this? As you can tell, I am new at this! :)

Comment: heh np. :-) Not sure about a specific piece of software, but you can google for it, i.e. spritesheet generator, etc.  _edit:_ by the way, image map is actually the wrong term. heh sorry about that.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Have you used Adobe Flash to generate the sprite sheets?

Answer (score 0):

For a game, a database approach would be too slow and i won't recommend it.

As @Miles Alden said, a image map is a good solution for small to medium images. It would be also wise to place them in an image with a size of a power of 2.

For large resolution images, I would recommend to store the filenames in a array (`JSON` or `PLIST` are the fastest to parse, or just *comma separated*) and load the images by the time you really need it.

Comment: Good to know. Do you recommend an specific software for the spritesheet creation?